# Help installing Ubuntu Desktop Next 15.04 from USB

Tags: boot, usb, mir, unity8

I would like to install Ubuntu Desktop Next 15.04's daily build from 12/31/14. I would like to know how to install this from a USB stick. I used the instructions on the Ubuntu website for normal installing, but when it boots, it brings me to a (sorta) graphical boot menu with options to do stuff like Install Ubuntu Desktop Next. When I try to do a live session or run the installer, it gets stuck on the boot menu. Could you please help me with this? I use a Gateway GT5622 with a Pentium E2160 running at 1.80 GHz with 3 Gibibytes (GiB, not Gigabytes or GB) of RAM.

I know, you may be saying "It's wrong to use an alpha", but I actually want to beta test Unity 8. I hope that gives some of you people downvoting just because "it's an alpha". I'm going to use it just to test!

EDIT: I realized I was being impatient. I'm sorry about that. I did get setup to work, but when I log in, it starts Mir but no Unity 8. Also, one person put in the comments that Ubuntu 15.04 is offtopic on Ask Ubuntu, is this true? I need to corroborate this information. I'll also try a different build if I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is still in alpha, hence will likely be very buggy as any bugs have not been fixed yet - you really should wait until atleast a beta release (Febuary/March 2015) or until is is released as stable (April 2015): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: I'm aware of that. Desktop Next isn't even alpha yet, unlike Ubuntu's main version (source code only) and it's derivatives (which have a full ISO image).

Comment: @NicholasJay if you are aware of that you will also know 15.04 is off topic on AU.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is?

Comment: @NicholasJay: hover with your mouse over Rinzwind's name...  **He's a god here**.  If he says something, you bow, mumble "thank you" and walk out backwards...  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using **15.04** *beta* (installed from USB)

### Creating [UEFI-only install] USB Drive:

- Download **.iso** file;
- Insert USB Drive; (*all content will be lost*)
- Start Disk Utility; (aka 'Disks')

  - Select the USB Drive;
  - Click on 'cog' icon, at top right
  - Select '*Restore Disk Image*', and navigate to .iso file;
  - Click 'Start Restoring'

---

- Insert USB Drive on target system.
- Reboot the System, and manually select UEFI 'boot' device.

---

Have fun!

Daniel

Comment: Desktop Next 15.04, not normal 15.04!

Comment: It seems to work now.